# Using `define inside Case statement not working

Tags: verilog, case-statement

I am trying to use a  `` `define `` inside a Verilog `case` statement for my design, but the edaplayground compiler throws the following error for all the lines wherever the  `` `define `` is used:

> ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: non-printable: \xe2."

If I use the  `` `define `` outside the `case` statement, then it works fine. Does Verilog not allow `define` inside `case`?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
`define AND 4’b0000
`define OR 4’b0001
`define ADD 4’b0010
`define SLL 4’b0011
`define SLLFunc 6’b000000
`define SRLFunc 6’b000010
`define SRAFunc 6’b000011
`define ADDFunc 6’b100000

module ALUControl(
  ALUCtrl,
  ALUOp,
  FuncCode);
  
  input [3:0]ALUOp;
  input [5:0]FuncCode;
  output reg [3:0]ALUCtrl;
  
  always@(*) begin
    if (ALUOp == 4'b1111) begin
      case(FuncCode)
        //Compiler throws error for the below 2 lines
        `SLLFunc: ALUCtrl = `SLL;
        default: ALUCtrl = `AND;
      endcase
    end else begin
      ALUCtrl = ALUOp;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Text macros do not understand Verilog syntax. It is just simple text replacement.

Your problem is with the editor used to create the `` `define ``. It is using a end-single-quote `’` instead of an accent/tick `'`.